# ¿Cuando se debe usar self en un Model en Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Dentro de un `Model`, cuando tengo en un método una operación de escritura de una variable, ¿porque es necesario agregar `self` para que funcione correctamente?

Por ejemplo, si tengo el siguiente código:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  beffore_save :make_rotting

  def make_rotting
    if age > 20
        self.rotting = true
    end    
  end

end
```

Por otro lado, si omito el self, no funiona:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  beffore_save :make_rotting

  def make_rotting
    if age > 20
        rotting = true  #No funciona correctamente
    end    
  end

end
```

**Nota**: la variable `age` la lee sin ningún problema en ambos casos.

¿Porque hay diferencia en el comportamiento de `rotting` con la presencia de `self`, mientras que en `age` no cambia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces `rotting = true`, lo que estás haciendo es declarar una variable local que funciona en el ámbito del método `make_rotting` y desaparecerá cuando la ejecución del método finalice.
Ahora, cuando llamas a `self.rotting = true`, estás pidiendo modificar el atributo `rotting` de tu instancia actual de `zombie`, que es como debería hacerse.

En general, en un método de instancia de un modelo, deberías usar `self` cuando modifiques atributos o cuando exista alguna ambiguedad entre llamar a una variable local y un atributo/método ya definido, por ejemplo:

```
  def make_rotting(age)
    if (age || self.age) > 20
        self.rotting = true
    end    
  end
```

La primera llamada a `age` hace referencia a la variable local que viene como parámetro del método, mientras que la segunda (`self.age`) hace referencia al atributo, sin que necesariamente estemos modificando este atributo.

Respecto a por qué es lo mismo llamar a `age` o `self.age` si el caso es solo leer un atributo, es por el orden en el que ruby trata de resolver la llamada a `age`:

- Primero revisa en el ámbito de `make_rotting` si existe alguna variable `age` definida.
- En caso de no encontrarle, buscará en el ámbito de la instancia de `zombie` si `age`está definido.

En caso de usar `self.age`, estás explícitamente indicando que busque la definición en la instancia de `zombie`.

Comment: Gran aporte, en particular la explicación del orden de resolución de la llamada a `age`. Muchas gracias.